# Does Session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("") guarantee order/contiguity of messages?

Tags: java, session, asynchronous, websocket, java-websocket

If I run:

```
session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("0");
session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("1");
session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("2");
```

to dispatch three strings to my clients through a websocket, are my clients guaranteed to receive messages in the following order?

```
0
1
2
```

I know this is the case if I use the blocking interface but not sure about the async interface.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html